# UWP printing failure: 0x80040154

Tags: printing, uwp

I've seen a complete failure of the ability to print from UWP apps on my PC, which has halted development.

The error that appears is 0x80040154.  All printers are affected.  No traditional steps to repair have been successful.

Desktop applications and modern Windows apps, like Mail, are unaffected.  Only UWP access to printers.

I suspect that some permission relating to COM interaction between UWP and a Microsoft print interface has been damaged, but I've not a clue how to diagnose and repair.  Has anyone seem anything similar to this and know how to dx and repair?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide the relevant code for calling the `printer`, or give a minimal runnable demo, which helps us find the cause of the problem?

Comment: All UWP printing code fails in this exact manner, including the “Printing C#” example in the Universal Windows Platform samples.

Comment: Hi, What is your system version? Have you tried replacing the printing device or running the print code on another machine, which may be related to the device?

Comment: It is definitely machine specific; all printing devices are affected, but only printing from UWP applications is affected.  Not sure that SO comments are appropriate place for you to quiz me about the details.

Comment: Hi, Through communication with the Microsoft engineering team, we confirmed that this is a known issue. Our team has noticed it and is working on it, thank you for your question.

Comment: Not useful.  Development is frozen, and MS support (yes, I paid the $500 homage) doesn't have a clue how to diagnose and is encouraging me to choose the nightmare scenarios of re-installing my operating system or restoring an old backup.  Dreadful support.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry that you have paid a lot for this. But I used the [printer sample provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) to connect with the local printer, and the connection is normal. I suggest you also try using the example to test, if the test passes, please check your code.

Comment: I face the same issue. Did you manage to solve this @zax? Pretty much everything else I tried failed. I'd appreciate if you can share your insights on this.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft gave up after many hours trying, and I restored from backup. MS senior level support for UWP sucks. And they kept the $500.